# How to iterate a for loop in reverse?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code:

```vb
Sub copyPaste()

' Copies data from A, pastes in E, for each "chunk" of rows

Dim Last As Integer
Dim emptyRow As Integer

With ActiveSheet

    Last = Range("A7391").End(xlUp).Row

    For emptyRow = Last To 2 Step 1

        If Not Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 20, ActiveCell.Column).Select

    Next emptyRow
End With

End Sub
```

I read comparable questions here, to no avail. I changed every value in the code. I removed the entire `If` section. I removed the line that starts with `Cells`. I F8'ed through the code a number of times.

I get to the `For emptyRow = Last To 2 Step 1` and it ***skips*** to `End With`.

Previously I didn't have `With/End With`, and it skipped straight to `End Sub`, but I read that I should add it and tried that.

I tried shutting down Excel and restarting the computer. I read that one should not use `.Select`, but I select the cell to copy it.

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(emptyRow, 1)) Then`. "I actually need to select the cell in order to copy it". No, that's incorrect. One does not need to `Select` a `Range` before calling `.Copy` on it.

Comment: What do you intend with `Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 20, ActiveCell.Column).Select`?

Comment: Stax! That was it! Phew. Much appreciated.

Comment: BigBen, the code is choosing the first cell in every block after the empty row. And I did change to your much more succinct code. Thank you.

Comment: Stax, you deleted the wrong comment. You deleted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step should be Negative if you're stepping backward through the range.
I.e. Step -1